# How can I add a new text box to my WPF from a DataSet?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

Okay so I'm trying to create a wpf where the number of textboxes on the screen are related to the number of rows in a DataTable that match a certain criteria. I want the TextBoxes to be populated based on data from the table.

What I've tried 1)

```
int numContacts = 0;
List<TextBox> list = new List<TextBox>();

IEnumerable<DataRow> selectedContacts = from myRow in 
   ds.Tables["contacts"].AsEnumerable()
   where myRow.Field<int>("company_ID") == 1
   select myRow;

try
{
    foreach (var item in selectedContacts)
    {
        list.Add(new TextBox());
        // Here Is where I would like to setup the text box
        // I'm not quite sure how I would do that though
        numContacts++;
    }
}
catch {}
```

Basically I want to set the properties like this:

```
TextBox[,] tb = new TextBox[numContacts, 3];
var width = txt_name.Width;
var height = txt_name.Height;
Thickness marginName = txt_name.Margin;

for (int i = 0; i < nametb.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    tb[i, 0] = new TextBox();
    tb[i, 0].HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    tb[i, 0].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    tb[i, 0].Name = "name"+i;
    tb[i, 0].Width = width;
    tb[i, 0].Height = height;
    tb[i, 0].Margin = new Thickness(marginName.Left, marginName.Top + (height+3)*(i+1), 0, 0);
    grid.Children.Add(tb[i, 0]);
}
```

So is Linq the best option for this? In the future I want to create the TextBoxes then poputlate them with information from each row and then eventually save them back into the DataTable if a user makes a change.

Here is how my DataTable is setup:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable contactTable = new DataTable("contacts");
contactTable.Columns.Add("company_ID", typeof(int));
contactTable.Columns.Add("name");
contactTable.Columns.Add("title");
contactTable.Columns.Add("email");
contactTable.Rows.Add(1, "Jim Bean", "CEO", "Jbean@acompany.ca");
contactTable.Rows.Add(1, "Tim Brown", "CFO", "tbrown@acompany.ca");
contactTable.Rows.Add(1, "Nancy Smith", "CTO", "nsmith@acompany.ca");
contactTable.Rows.Add(2, "Norman Jackson", "CEO", "njackson@bcompany.ca");
contactTable.Rows.Add(3, "Todd White", "CFO", "twhite@ccompany.ca");
ds.Tables.Add(contactTable);
```

Comment: I thought we should not use `DataTable` in `Wpf`?

Comment: Is there something I should be using instead?

Comment: Why are you not using one of the grid tools like Datadrid or Gridview?

Comment: maybe your own models with some custom `ObservableCollection`

Comment: This question makes me think that you should be directed to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130(v=vs.110).aspx) to learn *all* about WPF. You wouldn't go to a foreign country and try talking in the native language without taking lessons in that language, so why do so many people jump straight into the deep end with WPF, when they [appear to] know nothing about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're approaching this in the wrong way.  A strength of WPF is its ability to decouple from your data and rely on the markup to present the data for you.  This means you shouldn't be doing any presentation-layer work *programmatically*, but rather letting WPF do the work for you. This occurs with *binding*.

For example, rather than creating a presentation object in code, use WPF's markup to describe the data:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="True"
          CanUserDeleteRows="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding contacts}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding company_ID}"
                        Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding name}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding title}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding email}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now, by default, a `DataGridTextColumn` has the `IsReadonly` property set to `false`.  This means the cell will have the editable functionality you're looking for.  Because the cell is bound, a change to its value will propagate to the data source (if the property to which it is bound is not readonly).

Hopefully that points you in the right direction.  There are a few other nuances you'll encounter, but I recommend doing some research on [binding to a DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=datagrid%20binding%20%5Bwpf%5D).

To answer your question about whether or not LINQ is the right way to approach this -- I think that may be fine if you're using LINQ in some DataAccess layer to generate the classes (or *Models*) to which you'll bind your DataGrid.  However, I think you'll have to do some work in between LINQ and the DataGrid to handle [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete).